# include PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html

So I have this index.php page:

```
<?php 
 include main.php; 
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
  <title>MySite</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a id = "submit" href="submit.php">Submit</a>
  <br /> 
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <p id = "playing">Message</p>
  <?php 
   getMessage();
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

The include file main.php looks like this:

```
<?php
 function getMessage()
 {
  echo "Test";
 }
?>
```

But it is not echoing. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The include function has to be called like this: `include('main.php');`

Comment: Actually, `include 'main.php';` is also fine (as long as you have quotes around the filename) because `include` is a language construct, not a function.